# Different version require of CMake results dlopen "undefined symbol"

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dynamic-loading

I'm building with g++/KDevelop/CMake(3.16.3).

Before I put `cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0.0 )` in the first line of my CMakeLists.txt and everythings OK, now I need change it to `cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 )` because of other requirements.But with this I can **NOT** load the libs with new main program.

My programs are some little *.so libs as "Module", and be `dlopen` by the main program.

header.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
int GetNumber();
```

littleModule.cpp

```cpp
#include "header.hpp"
extern "C" int newStrategy() {
    return GetNumber();
};
```

loader.cpp

```cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "header.hpp"

int GetNumber() {
    return 123;
};

bool anyError( void* pFunc ) {
    const char* err_msg = dlerror();
    if( err_msg != nullptr ) {
        lg_erro << "Error on loading:" << err_msg;
        return true;
    }
    
    if( pFunc == nullptr ) {
        lg_erro << "Error on loading:NULL ptr";
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
};
    
using StrategyMaker_f = auto( * )()->int;
    
int main( int argc, char** args ) {
    void* pFunc = args; // any ptr not NULL
    
    // no err left before
    if( anyError( pFunc ) )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    
    auto lib_handle = dlopen( "/path/to/modules/littleModule.so", RTLD_NOW );
    if( anyError( lib_handle ) )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    
    pFunc = dlsym( lib_handle, "newStrategy" );
    if( anyError( pFunc ) )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    
    auto _mk_func = reinterpret_cast<StrategyMaker_f>( pFunc );
    lg_debg << "Success with:" << _mk_func();
    
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
};
```

CMakeLists.txt (loader.cpp)

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0.0 )
# cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 )
add_executable( loader Loader.cpp
    common/log/Log2Console.cpp
    common/misc/Converts.cpp
)
target_link_libraries( loader dl )
install( TARGETS loader RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} )
```

CMakeLists.txt (littleModule.cpp)

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0.0 )
# cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 ) still don't work
# add_library( littleModule SHARED littleModule.cpp )
# As @Tsyvarev's hint
add_library( littleModule MODULE littleModule.cpp )
set_target_properties( littleModule PROPERTIES
    PREFIX              ""
    OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE littleModule
    OUTPUT_NAME_DEBUG   littleModule
    VERSION             ${PROJECT_VERSION}
)
install( TARGETS littleModule LIBRARY DESTINATION strategies )
```

Error Output:

> Error on loading:undefined symbol: _Z9GetNumberv

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact** error message. BTW, dynamically loaded modules in CMake are created using `MODULE` keyword passed to the `add_library`, not as SHARED libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! error msg is :"undefined symbol: _Z9GetNumberv", the result is same with MODULE

Comment: Using `nm` for your executable, you could find out exact name of the symbol, representing function `GetNumber`. Compare this name with one in the error message (`_Z9GetNumberv`).

Comment: I confirmed with nm, there is `_Z9GetNumberv` in the executable.

Comment: You should pass option `-rdynamic` to the linking of program `loader`. CMake is a very flexible and user-friendly program, which I do not know at all. With `make` it would be something like this: `loader: LDFLAGS += -rdynamic`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond - CMake _highly_ discourages messing with raw flags. This feature is modeled by the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property (as detailed in my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by policy [CMP0065](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0065.html) which states:

> New in version 3.4.
>
> Do not add flags to export symbols from executables without the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> CMake 3.3 and below, for historical reasons, always linked executables on some platforms with flags like `-rdynamic` to export symbols from the executables for use by any plugins they may load via `dlopen`. CMake 3.4 and above prefer to do this only for executables that are explicitly marked with the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> The `OLD` behavior of this policy is to always use the additional link flags when linking executables regardless of the value of the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> The `NEW` behavior of this policy is to only use the additional link flags when linking executables if the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property is set to `True`.
>
> This policy was introduced in CMake version 3.4. Unlike most policies, CMake version 3.24.0-rc2 does *not* warn by default when this policy is not set and simply uses `OLD` behavior. See documentation of the `CMAKE_POLICY_WARNING_CMP0065` variable to control the warning.
>
> Note: The `OLD` behavior of a policy is deprecated by definition and may be removed in a future version of CMake.

Hence, CMake is working as intended. Indeed this is a reasonable policy; adding such flags affects how the linker loads libraries and can have performance consequences when such functionality isn't actually used.

To fix *your* program, write:

```
add_executable(loader
    Loader.cpp
    common/log/Log2Console.cpp
    common/misc/Converts.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(loader PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
set_target_properties(loader PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS TRUE)
```

The last line is the important one for your problem; it will make sure that symbols in your executable are available to dynamically loaded libraries/plugins. The change from `dl` to `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` is to account for systems which don't have a separate `dl` lib or have it named differently (for instance most BSDs including macOS, and HP-UX).