# How to add symbolic links for MODULE in cmake like for shared lib?

Tags: cmake, module, shared-libraries, symlink, suffix

I'm using cmake-3.16, and for other technical reason, I must use `MODULE` to make a shared lib(*.so) in Linux instead of using `SHARED`.

But with `MODULE`, cmake does **NOT** produce target file with name like "libDummy.so.x.x.x", and automatically create a symbolic link with name like "libDummy.so".

So I manually use `OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE` to declare the target name as following:

```
add_library( Dummy MODULE Dummy.cpp )
set_target_properties( Dummy PROPERTIES
    PREFIX              ""
    SUFFIX              ""
    OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE "Dummy.so.${PROJECT_VERSION}"
    OUTPUT_NAME_DEBUG   "Dummy.so.${PROJECT_VERSION}"
)
install( TARGETS Dummy LIBRARY DESTINATION somewhere )
```

But I don't know how to add a symbolic link for it.
I found the cmake command:

`file( CREATE_LINK "Origin.so.0.1.2" "Symlnk.so" RESULT act_res SYMBOLIC )`

looks like doing my requirement.
But I don't Known its syntax. I searched in cmake documents, there are very less comments about it.

How to refer the target name of the original Module in the command `file( CREATE_LINK )`,

and how to make the symbolic link with relative path,

and how to store the symblink into the same folder of the module?

Thx!

Comment: Can you explain more about why you "must" use `MODULE`? Normally this would happen automatically for a shared library if you set the `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850419/different-version-require-of-cmake-results-dlopen-undefined-symbol